# force_ssl redirect loop on Rails 4 using CloudFlare SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, https, cloudflare

I get a redirect loop on my Rails 4 app when enforcing ssl with the `force_ssl` method (SSL implemented using CloudFlare's one-click SSL capabilities).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This stopped happening when I switched from "flexible" to the "full" SSL setting in CloudFlare.

Comment: I am having this problem with Full SSL enabled. In the end I had to remove force_ssl and rely on Cloudflare page rules, which is fine, but I'd rather just do it through rails.

Comment: @stephenmurdoch I had to do that too, but that does produce some weird errors -- like the app does still send requests to http from time to time, which causes weird errors in Safari and on iPhone (like the page just doesn't load, almost like the button is dead).

Comment: Hmm this seems to cause a `SSL handshake failed` error from CloudFlare. :/

Answer (score 4):

Cloudflare's trying to force connect via HTTP because your server doesn't have HTTPS, but your app is forcing SSL.

### Problem

This happens in a specific set of circumstances:

1. Your Cloudflare (CF) SSL setting is `Flexible` and HTTP is allowed between CF and Heroku.
2. Your server or Heroku instance's SSL isn't setup, so it's forcing the connection between HTTP

What happens is:

1. You connect to the domain via `HTTPS`
2. Cloudflare steps in to handle the SSL part, and tries to fetch the app over plain HTTP from the server
3. The server sees a connection over HTTP and redirects to HTTPS
4. Go to step 1

This causes an infinite redirect loop.

### Solution

Upgrade your application server to HTTPS, this solves the redirect issue. Then, just to be safe, switch Cloudflare to `Full`.

**First:** I configured SSL on my server. In my case, I was using Heroku, which can use Let's Encrypt to provision SSL automatically. You would use Let's Encrypt directly if you weren't. Cloudflare also provides self-signed origin certificates, but why bother when Let's Encrypt is easy and free.

**Second:** I configured my app to force SSL by adding the following to `production.rb`

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

**Third:** Since I no longer needed an HTTP connection between my server and Cloudflare, I switched it to from `Flexible` to `Full`. If you've used Let's Encrypt or a CA to provision the server's certificate, you can switch to `Flexible (Strict)`.